# Off Grid Circuitikz Symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, grids

Shouldn't circuits line up on the grids? Otherwise, drawing code get messy -- really quick. I have found pins-to-grid alignment to be common practice in most the Schematic/Diagram programs I have used, such as Altium, Eagle, and Visio.  It seems that an [alternative latex circuit](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/) does this as well. I have attached their example drawing to demonstrate. The author seems to have shifted some parts by 0.5 grid spacing, but it looks like all the components could align to grid had the author wanted.

Are my settings wrong? I just started using tikz and maybe I am missing something.  Is it hard to fix the coded symbols, i.e, is this something a newbee like me can fix and share back on https://github.com/mredaelli/circuitikz? Thanks.

```
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\draw (3,3) node[transformer] (T1) {};
\draw (3,3) node[op amp] (U1) {};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can see that it's actually on the grid. Add `\draw (T1.base) -- (0,0);` to see where it's anchor is. If you want to position it on the grid you can use a different anchor.

Comment: Yes, the parts are anchored to the grid.... but none of the terminal align to the grid (where all connections are made).  The transformer is anchored at 3,3 but none of the terminals are. This makes drawing anything very difficult.

Comment: @gpitel Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Could you also explain (or illustrate) how you want the nodes to be placed? Why do you need the “terminals” (?) to be aligned on the grid? Why don’t you use the node’s anchors? For example (p. 32 of the [`circuitikz` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf)), the `op amp` shape defines the anchors `.+`, `.-` and `.out` (as well as `.down` and `.up`) which can be used to connect.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I edited my original question in response to your request.

Comment: Without  a MWE of your code, we can't really help. Please edit one in and request reopening.